# NGINX Proxy Pass Without Redirecting (302)

Tags: nginx

The below code will allow any /files/* url on my domain to load the url from example.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/files/* instead.

The issue however, is that when visiting example.com/files/somefile.png, the browser will trigger a 302 redirect to example.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/files/somefile.png - this reveals my private url and since all the files are public, one could list the files and download them all.

Is there a way to hide these urls (not redirect)?

PS. Yes, I've read many other stackoverflow topics on this and can't seem to find a solid answer. Proxy Redirect Off setting seems to make no difference.

**Nginx:**

```
    # Proxy AWS S3 (digital ocean spaces)
    location /files {
        set $s3_bucket        'example.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com';
        set $url_full         '$1';

        proxy_http_version     1.1;
        proxy_set_header       Host $s3_bucket;
        proxy_set_header       Authorization '';
        proxy_hide_header      x-amz-id-2;
        proxy_hide_header      x-amz-request-id;
        proxy_hide_header      x-amz-meta-server-side-encryption;
        proxy_hide_header      x-amz-server-side-encryption;
        proxy_hide_header      Set-Cookie;
        proxy_ignore_headers   Set-Cookie;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;

        resolver               8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8 valid=300s;
        resolver_timeout       10s;

        proxy_pass             http://$s3_bucket$url_full;
    }
```

Comment: Richard, could you write the proxy_redirect rule? It would just need to redirect anything from /files (on the s3 bucket) to /files (at my domain)? It's just that I'm really bad at writing these rules and it takes a while to get them right

Comment: Do I just set proxy_redirect 'Location'; (the location from the curl -I response?)

Comment: I set this proxy_redirect http://example.com/files/ http://$s3_bucket/files/; - the urls are still redirecting however. curl -I 'url' triggers a 301 redirection to the https version of the url. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean by https version. What URL are you trying to fix in your question. That is the URL that you should be using `curl` with. You need the exact text of the `Location` header. Edit your question and add the `curl -I` command and the response headers and then we may be able to suggest a `proxy_redirect` value that might work.

Comment: I got it working! The solution was actually finding my mistake - I had used http when I needed to use https, because my server redirects http. I also set the proxy_redirect params in the wrong order, when I corrected that it works with (or without) the proxy_redirect setting! Thank you Richard you're a life saver!